# Unknown prop `active` on <img> tag

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using [Carousel from react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#carousels), so whenever the class of anyone of the img goes `active` js throws me a warning

```
Unknown prop `active` on <img> tag. Remove this prop from the element. For details, see ...
in img (at nav.js:13)
in LinkContainer (at nav.js:12)
in div (at nav.js:10)
in Navigation (at app.js:15)
in div (at app.js:13)
in App (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router (at routes.js:8)
in div (at index.js:13)
```

I don't think any file is needed because it looks like a fault in the design of react-bootstrap itself but here is the Carousel file

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Carousel} from "react-bootstrap";
import img1 from "./images/Screenshot (1).jpg";
import img2 from "./images/Screenshot (2).jpg";
import img3 from "./images/Screenshot (3).jpg";
import "./carousel.css";

export default class Slideshow extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Carousel pauseOnHover={true} interval={3000}>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img className="slide-image" alt="900x500" src={img1}/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>First slide label</h3>
                        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img className="slide-image" alt="900x500" src={img2}/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img className="slide-image" alt="900x500" src={img3}/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        </div>
    )
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of webpack are you using?

Comment: looking at `yarn.lock` it shows `webpack "2.6.1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a known issue which is now closed. Check here : [issues react-bootstrap](https://recordnotfound.com/react-bootstrap-react-bootstrap-4650/issues)

Upgrade to the latest version [v0.31.1](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) on this date.

Conclusion: It's a react-bootstrap issue and since its a warning, you may ignore it.

Comment: yeah that's the version I have

Comment: The issue seems to be closed, then maybe it will be release in next ver.